# Easy alternate query for knowing user privileges in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if there are any easy alternate query available in SQL Server for knowing user privileges as like following, which are available in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user_role_privs;
SELECT * FROM role_sys_privs;
SELECT * FROM user_sys_privs;
```

Comment: Please don't spam-tag your posts. Your question is about SQL Server - no need for three Oracle tags then (including for SQL Developer - why???)

Comment: yes sir, i will take care about that

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120912/how-to-view-the-roles-and-permissions-granted-to-any-database-user-in-azure-sql