# How to use Timed Trigger Azure Function in isolated process with identity-based connections?

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-managed-identity

I'm having hard time troubleshooting the Azure identity-based connection to an Azure sql database from an Azure Function in isolated process. I'm using .NET6, Azure Function V4 and EF6.

Here is the FunctionApp package references

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.25" />
```

And here's the program.cs boilerplate

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((builderContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        var cs = builderContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        services.AddDbContext<InternalDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cs));
        services.AddTransient<IDbContext>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<InternalDbContext>());
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

What am I missing here ?

Looking for solutions, I reviewed some MS Tutorials [functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity) and [functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2) (except for using TimedTrigger instead of ServiceBusTrigger...) but everything seems fine...

And I still get this error
`Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.`

Everything works fine if I change the connection string to use the sql admin user/password.

I tried adding Azure.Identity package reference but did not work.

Then I was looking for manually adding AddIdentity or UseManagedIdentity kinda extension but did not find any... and actually I just think it should not be necessary, but maybe I'm wrong...

Note that I'm familiar with app services using managed identity with the same connection string and having no issues. But this time it's my first time from an Azure Function, and seems not as easy then app services...

Comment: Can you confirm the managed identity has permission to access the database ? you can check the role permission in sql like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145318/4167200

Comment: Also are you using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package ?

Comment: And could you paste your connection string as well please ?

Comment: I confirm: From Azure role assignments, the assigned identity is Contributor of the sql database

Comment: EF6.SqlServer v6.0.25 (latest) pull Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v2.1.4

Comment: connection string is: Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net;Database=mydatabase;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;TrustServerCertificate=True

Comment: RBAC Role `Contributor` does not grant access to the database: it is a management role. from the arcticle you've posted, there is a section related to grant access to the database: [Grant SQL database access to the managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity#grant-sql-database-access-to-the-managed-identity)

Comment: I mean, Azure sql database resources access is granted with 'Contributor' built-in role https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

And about the db user roles assignement, here it is: db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin.

Answer (score 0):

- To use Identity based connection, enable `System Assigned Identity` in Function and copy the `Object(principal) ID`.

[image]

- Also Enable `System Assigned Identity` in the Azure SQL Server

[image]

- Set the Admin in the server in `Microsoft Entra ID` and paste the `Object(principal) ID` and select the `Enterprise Application`.

[image]

[image]

This worked for me.

I have created a timer function to get data from the database using `EntityFrameworkCore`

**#My Data:**

[image]

**#MyCode:**
**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Azure.Core;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly MyDbContext _dbcontext;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            _dbcontext = dbContext;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")] TimerInfo Timer, FunctionContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            try
            {
                // Fetch data from SQL Server using Entity Framework
                var data = await _dbcontext.SampleTable.ToListAsync();

                // Process or log the fetched data
                foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id}, Name: {item.Name}, Age: {item.Age}");
                    }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
         public DbSet<SampleTable> SampleTable { get; set; }
}

public class SampleTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()    
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext,services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=tcp:demosqldbserver123.database.windows.net;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;Database=demosqlserver;"
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
   
  }
}
```

**`.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.25" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vivek to share a working solution.
Can you share what EF library version your solution is using please ?

Comment: There is one thing tho. Forcing the Azure Function identity to be the SQL Server admin is not acceptable in my context because there are multiple app that access the same server and they all use different identities. Also, sql server admin need to be set for a specific AD group dedicated for IT users.

'Contributor' role are assigned to the azure resources for those identities and it should work fine. (it works for Azure App Service I can tell :)...)

Comment: Actually I've tested this solution without providing any SQL database access to the user and still work, because the identity is the sql server admin. 

So I think it slightly defer how should use the managed identity at the SQL database level, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity#grant-sql-database-access-to-the-managed-identity

Comment: @Jack If you do not want to change the `Admin` then you can create a `User` inside the Database `CREATE USER [FunctionappName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` and assign the user `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` role to the Functionapp name user.

Comment: @Jack Added my .`csproj` file

Comment: Thank you Vivek. In the end I resolve my issue by fixing the azure function name mismatch and recreate the sql user to match the exact identity name. 
More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1460971/does-timed-trigger-azure-function-in-isolated-proc